# how to return only one column from nested select for mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

hello I have question on nested select in mysql. I want a working query which can achieve the goal what the dummy query below intends to achieve:

```
select t1.col1 from t1
  where t1.col2 in
  (select t3.col2, t3.col3 from t3
     order by t3.col3 limit NUM)
```

Well basically speaking, t1.col2 should be in the nest selected t3.col2, but the nested select should order by another column which is t3.col3.

Comment: Could you be more specific, are you saying you just want to put an order at the end?

Comment: @MatthewRiches Outer select should select a certain group of t1.col2. To get that certain group, I have to use nested select. So the inner select provides the sorted result based on t3.col3, and at the same time the top NUM of t3.col2 should be returned to the outer select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatenly, `MySQL` does not support `LIMIT` for queries used with `IN`.

Try this:

```
SELECT  col1
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT col2
        FROM    (
                SELECT  col2
                FROM    t3
                ORDER BY
                        col3
                LIMIT   5
                ) q
        ) q
JOIN    t1
USING   (col2)
```

Comment: @PeitiPeterLi: if there are duplicates of `col2`, like `1, 2, 1, 3, 1`, how do you want them sorted?